# Why Google Bigquery Datetime Format is with a 'T' separator? I want a space separator

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I am creating table in BigQuery with schema from json file and giving DATETIME datatype to a column. Then i have simply loaded data from a csv in the datetime format of 2020-01-01 00:00:00 but when it goes into bigquery, i can see it is having a 'T' separator i.e. 2020-01-01T00:00:00.

Its even mention on google bigquery docs - YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]] , ( |T): A space or a `T` separator. But i dont know how to give a space separator instead of the default T separator. Please help. Thanks.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types

Comment: the 'T' is just the default separator between date and time in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted datetime strings

Comment: yeah but any way i can get a space separator, any way to specify that while loading data or creating the table?

Comment: Where can you see the date format? Dates are stored in whatever binary format the engine sees fit. Date formats are used to convert from/to strings, i.e., they're a display feature.

Comment: Problem occudrs when i am exporting the bq data and keeping it on cloud storage location. Then running HQL job to create hive table with same bq table schema. So problem is that the timestamp dtype in hive table is picking this bq datetime dtype value as NULL and not the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss that i want. I tried with bq timestamp dtype but that too stores the date and time and appends UTC at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is using the [Datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#format_datetime) function:

```
FORMAT_DATETIME(format_string, datetime_expression)
```

For example:

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql \
"SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2020-01-01 13:45:55') AS datetime;"

+---------------------+
|      datetime       |
+---------------------+
| 2020-01-01 13:45:55 |
+---------------------+
```